# breakout of recursion and return value in java

Tags: java

I am trying to find the value of f1 which I am able to print, but somehow it is not returning the same. Can anybody tell what's wrong with it.

```
public String walk(String folderpath) {
    String f1 = "";
    File root = new File(folderpath);
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    if (list == null) return f1;

    for (File f : list) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            walk(f.getAbsolutePath());
            f1 = f.getAbsolutePath();
            if (f1.contains("foldername")) {
                System.out.println(+f1);
            }      
        }
    }           
    return f1;       
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Though it finding the folder name, the loop still goes on in your current code and it keep assigning the latest absolute path to the variable `f1` and you'll get the last value in the loop.

To avoid that you can return right away in if condition.

```
public String walk(String folderpath) {

    String f1 = "";

    File root = new File(folderpath);
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    if (list == null)
        return f1;
    for (File f : list) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            walk(f.getAbsolutePath());
            f1 = f.getAbsolutePath();

            if (f1.contains("foldername")) {

                return f1;   // return after you found it

            }

        }

    }

    return f1;
}
```

Comment: its still not giving what i wanted(folder path) instead it is giving the previous folder path

Comment: Can you show me what you are getting and what do you want ?

Comment: there are two return statements in the code, both are returning different Strings.In the first return statement i am getting what i want but 2nd statement is not returning the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String walk( String folderpath ) {

    String f1 = "";

    File root = new File( folderpath );
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    if (list == null) return f1;
    for ( File f : list ) {
        if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
        walk( f.getAbsolutePath() );
        f1=f.getAbsolutePath();

            if(f1.contains("foldername"))
            {

                System.out.println(+f1);
return f1; 
            }   

        }


    }

 return "noFolderName";             
}
```

Here you directly return the value when you got it.
And if you need to continue your foreach, store the f1 value in another variable instead of returning it in the if and return this new value at the end.